# Arrange tuples pairs into a dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm trying to search for every number in the tuples and put its other pair in a list as a value

number of nodes is given but I didn't use it

I don't understand the mistake, How can i fix it?

```
nodes_number = 4
dic = defaultdict(list)
my_list = [(0,1),(1,2),(3,1)] 
for i in my_list:
    dic[i[0]].append(i[1])
return dic
```

my code output

```
{0: [1], 1: [2], 3: [1]}
```

Output required

```
{0: [1], 1: [0, 2, 3], 2: [1], 3: [1]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to add both (x,y) and (y,x):

```
dic = defaultdict(list)
my_list = [(0,1),(1,2),(3,1)] 
for x, y in my_list:
    dic[x].append(y)
    dic[y].append(x)
```

Comment: thanks now its working but is there other way using the nodes_number ? because its taking more time for many tuples

Comment: Node numbers is not needed. I am not sure how you could use it in the first case. I am not sure how adding code that looks at the node number would speed this function up in any way.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the reverse of each pair as well.

Comment: thanks now its working but is there other way using the nodes_number ?

Comment: You could use it to initialize the dict with empty lists.

Comment: Can you show me how because my code takes more time for big tuples